# Import New Invoices From QuickBooks To MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, integration, quickbooks

I am looking for a way to import only new invoices and relevant data from Quickbooks Enterprise 14.0 to a MySQL Database. I am looking to run the process every hour or so which is why I want to pull only new invoices that have been created since the last request.

So far I have been able to mirror the Quickbooks Company File to my database using ConsoliBYTE QuickBooks Integration for PHP, however I cannot figure out how to import only new invoices and relevant data.

Any help would be appreciated. I've looked at some of the other scripts within the ConsoliBYTE QuickBooks Integration for PHP package but couldn't quite work it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code. Post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @KeithPalmerJr.

At the moment I have only used the following file and have changed only the server address and domain name located within the file as instructed via the PHP comments: 

quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/example_mysql_mirror_qwc

I haven't created any code for the continuous import procedure yet as I'm at a loss where to begin and would appreciate some help to get me on the right tracks.

Thanks,

Comment: Without seeing what you have so far, we can not help you.